# using nav menu id's

Tags: wp-query

I am trying to make a WP_Query that gets all pages / posts from the navigation id. I have the id's. I have a variable that holds the numbers and when I echo it out, this is exactly what I get

7,43,20,22,16,1051,18,26,9,24,28,10523

Reading in the codex, I should be able to use page_id. When I refresh the page, I do not get any posts or pages. Having tried many different versions of this query, this is where I am at right now.

```
 $page_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => array( 'post', 'page'), 'page_id' => array($number)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have posts and pages then `page_id` isn't the correct parameter. You should probably use `post__in`.  See [`WP_Query Parameters`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters).

Additionally, `post__in` accepts an array, whereas you have a string, so you'll need to use PHP to [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string into an array.

This is untested, but I think it should do it:

```
$ids = '7,43,20,22,16,1051,18,26,9,24,28,10523';
$ids = explode(",", $ids);
$page_query = new WP_Query( 'post__in' => $ids, 'nopaging' => true );
```

`nopaging` should do it, or `"posts_per_page" => -1`  if it doesn't.

Comment: $number was already an array. I was using the implode function to add the comma because I thought the syntax for post__in would have been 1,2,3,4. As it is, there are no comas in the array. So wouldn't the syntax be wrong? The code you posted works better but only returns 3 out of 12 pages

Comment: Look again at the Parameters link I posted. `post__in` definitely accepts an array. There shouldn't be commas in the array, each ID is a different value in the array. Only 3 are displayed? Under reading options, is "posts per page" set to 3? Possibly, just need to add a parameter to show all the posts. See edit.

Comment: yep, I did have it settings set to 3. I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you for your help.